Both K and alpha are non-negative real numbers , then how to get the the second inequality?
Both K and alpha are non-negative real numbers , then how to get the the second inequality?
\begin{array}{l}
0\leqq \frac{\mathrm{M}}{K} \sum_{p = k+1}^{\infty} \frac{(K \alpha)^{p}}{p!} \\
\leqq \frac{M}{K} \frac{(K \alpha)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{(K \alpha)^{p}}{p!}
\end{array}
I am self-teaching An Introduction to Odinary Differential Equations by Earl , and  in fact, the inequality comes from  P213 of the book to estimate the speed when  Picard sequence is approahing to the solution.

\begin{align*}
&\text{Given that } f(x) = e^x \text{ and } a = 0:\\
&\text{Since } f^{(n)}(x) = e^x \text{ for all } n \geq 0\\
&\text{And } f^{(j)}(0) = 1 \text{ for all } j \geq 0\\
&e^x - \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j!}x^j\right) = \frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\\
&\text{Since } e^x \text{ is increasing and } c < x:\\
&e^c < e^x\\
&\text{Therefore:}\\
&e^x - \left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) < \frac{e^x}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
\end{align*}

This is unreadable. Why are you using all those \text commands?

I will fix it soon.Thx!
